# How do I get jQuery to change CSS based on multiple radio button selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that shows a block of HTML if a radio button is selected, however, I want to now add another option that will also display the HTML block. How can I ask if one OR the other?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='giftType']").click(function () {
        $('#memHonForm').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'memGift') ? 'block':'none');
    });
});
```

I need to add the value of 'honGift' as well. I have tried using || and commas to separate the two but that didn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When you use #element in the jquery selector its because its an id, and when its an id its for a single element.
Try a css class to your elements and point like this:

```
$('.element').css('display','')
```

Comment: I changed it to a class instead, but right now it's only displaying if the input 'memGift' is selected and I'm trying to get it to be 'memGift' OR 'honGift' which will display the .memHonForm block. I'm just asking what the format should be for two or more values - for some reason I can't find documentation online.

I have tried 'memGift','honGift' and 'memGift' || 'honGift'

Answer (score 0):

If add new option to show html block (suppose form), using new radio button, we must add checking for new radio button value (honGift) property in condition too, the modified line code will be:

```
 $('#memHonForm').css('display',($(this).val()=== 'memGift') || ($(this).val()=== 'honGift') ? 'block': 'none');
```

Imagine your simplified html code is something like this:

```
<body> 
<input id="memGift" type="radio" name="giftType" value="memGift"> menGift 
<input id="honGift" type="radio" name="giftType" value="honGift"> honGift 
<input type="radio" name="giftType" value="otherGift" CHECKED> otherGift
 <form id="memHonForm" style="display:none">
 <p>This is a Form!</p> 
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready( function(){ 
$( "input[name='giftType']").click( function() {    $('#memHonForm').css('display',($(this).val()=== 'memGift') || ($(this).val()=== 'honGift') ? 'block': 'none'); 
}
) 
});
 </script>
 </body>
```